# creating COM object in Vista- error

Tags: security, com, windows-vista

Is there special security settings needed for a server side VB script to create a COM object on Vista (64 bit, Enterprise) ? The COM object (a DLL) is registered. THanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "server side VB Script"? Which host runs the script?

Comment: That is -- is the VBScript run as part of an ASP page, from the command-prompt as a WScript/CScript or in some other context?

Answer (score 0):

What is your error message, as I known, a COM object must be created successfully in a certain amount of time in Vista, or else there will be a time-out error.